# INVALID_FIELD_WHEN_USING_TEMPLATE, When a template is specified the plain text body, html body, subject and charset may not be specified

Tags: apex, community

i fetching this type error ,while i trying to send email base of opportunity . code mentions below ..

```
public class OpportunityEmailNotification1 implements  Database.Batchable<SObject> {


    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {

        return Database.getQueryLocator(  [SELECT Id,name,ownerid,accountID, Channel_Partner_KAM_Email__c,Channel_Partner_Manager__c,CloseDate,
                                            Account.KAM__r.email,  Account.TL_for_Integration__r.email,
                                            Account.SAM_for_Integration__r.email ,RecordType.Developername
                                            FROM opportunity  where Status__c =:'Open']);



        }



        public static Map<String,    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> createDummyEmail(EmailTemplate templateName, List<String> whatIds){
        //  templateId  must be ID of an Email template
        //  targetObjId must be a Contact Id -- also used in merge fields of template recipient.xxxx
        //  whatId      must be an SObject that is used in the merge fields of the template relatedTo.xxxx
        //  fromId      if non null, use current user, otherwise, use this ID (most likely an org wide no reply id)
        Contact cnt = [Select Id, FirstName, Email From Contact Where Email != Null LIMIT 1];

       Map<String,  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> oppEmail = new   Map<String,    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();   

       List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> msgList= new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); 

       for(String whatID :whatIds){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();        
        msg.setTemplateId(templateName.id );
        msg.setWhatId(whatID);
        msg.setTargetObjectId(cnt.id);
        msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{[Select Email From User where name=:'narendra jagwan'].Email});
        msgList.add(msg);
      oppEmail.put(whatID, msg );   
   }      
        // Send the emails in a transaction, then roll it back
        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        Messaging.sendEmail(msgList); // Dummy email send
        Database.rollback(sp); // Email will not send as it is rolled Back
        // Send Actual email  
        system.debug(':::::::::::SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS:::::::::::'+oppEmail);

        for(id key :oppEmail.keyset()){
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
         List<String> ccTo = new List<String>(); 
         msg1.setTemplateId(templateName.id);
           ccTo.add('a_narendra.jagwan@airtel.com');
          msg1.setToAddresses(ccTo);
           msgList.add(msg1);
        }
         Messaging.sendEmail(msgList);
        return oppEmail;
    }  


    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, list<opportunity> records) {
        list <String> testString = new list<String>();

         id oppID;     
         String ChannelKAMEmail ;
         String ChannelPartnerEmail ;
         date closerDate;  

         Contact cnt = [select id from Contact  limit 1];
          system.debug('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'+cnt );  
         EmailTemplate em =[SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'CP - Opportunity Expected Closure date Alert'];

         system.debug('TTTTTTTT'+em );
         system.debug('AAAAAAAAAAAAA'+records); 
         for(opportunity  opp :records){
             oppID= opp.id;
             closerDate= opp.CloseDate ; 
             if(Date.Today() == closerDate-1|| Date.Today() ==closerDate-3 || Date.Today()==closerDate-5){  
               testString.add(oppID); 
              }
          }
           createDummyEmail( em , testString);


    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        // No need to do anything, but this needs to be here

    }   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error with setToAddresses(toAddresses) field . According to docs

> Optional. A list of email addresses to which you are sending the
>   email. The maximum number of email addresses allowed is 100. This
>   argument is allowed only when a template is not used.
>   So you need to remove this. More detail about this can be found in [official docs.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setToAddresses)